# How do I make this file from codepen work on vsc?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, codepen

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kathykato/12columns/master/12columns.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="gallery.css">
```

I added a few links in my header
but the output isnt the same as on code pen
I noticed on codepen it says the preprocessor is SCSS. Do I need to undertake any extra steps for this? Googling has only left me more confused as to why the links aren't working[Codepen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Dmpj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first file you linked to is a `.scss` file (a SASS CSS file). Your browser cannot read such a file - it needs to be 'preprocessed' by a SASS capable preprocessor which turns such a file into CSS.

In your case, though, you're better off just downloading the already processed [`*.min.css`](https://github.com/kathykato/12columns) file and using that.